# Checking if mac-address is present on network still doesn't work (ping -b and arp)

Tags: command-line, networking, bash, scripts, ping

This is kind of a follow up to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1349153/checking-if-a-mac-address-is-present-on-my-network-is-working-unreliably) post of mine.

I have the mac-address of my phone (samsung galaxy S9; though it shouldn't matter). I want to check if it's on the network or not. It doesn't have a static ip, so I need to check it using it's mac-address.

I'll refer to the mac-address of my phone with `[1]`.

- On my phone, random mac-address for the network is turned off (this wasn't the case in that previous post). It used to generate a random mac-address every time it connected to my network, now it doesn't.
- This is what I do to check if the mac-address is on the network:

  ```
  ping -b 192.168.2.255 -c 20
  arp | grep -i "[1]"
  ```

This is the "log" of the events:

```bsh
#phone connected to network
ping -b 192.168.2.255 -c 20 &> /dev/null
arp | grep -i "[1]"
-> successful

#phone NOT connected to network (turned of wifi on phone)
ping -b 192.168.2.255 -c 20 &> /dev/null
arp | grep -i "[1]"
-> successful
```

The second time, it shouldn't be successful. The phone isn't connected to the network, but it still shows it in the arp output.

My phone doesn't have a static ip-address, but when connecting it to the network, it almost always gets the same ip-address. That's fine. The `ping -b` output has always been correct. When my phone is connected to the network, I see the ip-address that it almost always gets in the list (of the `ping` command). When my phone isn't connected, I never see it's "standard" ip-address in the output. So ping works and is "up-to-date".

So I assume that arp isn't "up-to-date" as ping is (but this is just my raw guess). I think that arp doesn't update it's table eventhough ping has "made" a new one. But that is what I think based on a comment of the previous post: "*You are already doing a broadcast ping, ping -b 192.168.2.255. This should refill the arp table for any online devices with ip address 192.168.2.*.*"

Help!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **ARP** table to determine whether your phone connected to network or not, you have to remove your phone's **ARP** entry from your computer's **ARP** table. Otherwise you won't be able to determine change, because previous entry remains still.

You can remove specific **ARP** entry with `arp -d <IP_ADDR>` command, and remove all entries with `sudo ip neigh flush all`.

But, I think you should use **nmap** for scanning, besides you won't need to clean **ARP** table anymore. You can use this script.

```
#!/bin/bash

mac="$1"
# Scanning network, and obtaining IP address of specfied MAC address, if exists.
PHONEIP=$(sudo  nmap -sP -n 192.168.2.0/24 | grep -B2 "$mac" | grep -Eoi "192\.168\.2\.[0-9]+")
if [[ $PHONEIP == "" ]];then
    echo "$MAC not found."
else
    echo "$MAC found at $PHONEIP"
fi
```

But you have to give your Phone's MAC address as first argument, or you can change the line `mac="$1"` to `mac="<your-phone-mac>"`.

Note: You will need super user privileges to use this script.